# Why does the following sequence of random variables converge in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Given a sequence of points $t_1,t_2 \dots$ which is dense in $[t_0,T]$ and includes $T$ and

Given a sequence of stochastic processes 
$\xi_n(t)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^m$ living on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ that is stochastically continuous from the right i.e

$\lim_{t_{k_r} \to t}\mathbb{P}\{\vert \xi(t_{k_r})-\xi(t)\vert >\epsilon\}=0$ such that it has the same finite dimensional distribution (not for every $t$ but  for $t_1,t_2,t_3, \dots $ in the sequence above ) as that of the $\mathbb{R}^m$-valued random variable $x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)} \dots$ living on the probability space ($\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}'$). That is for all borel sets(and all $k \in \mathbb{N}$) $A_1,\dots A_k \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)$

$\mathbb{P}'\{x_1^{(n)}\in A_1, \dots ,x_k^{(n)} \in A_k\}=\mathbb{P}\{\xi_n(t_1) \in A_1, \dots , \xi_n(t_k) \in A_k\}$

I do not understand why should $x_{k_r}^{(n)}$ converge in probability as a consequence of the convergence in probability of $\xi(t_{k_r})$ to $\xi(t)$ as a consequence of stochastic continuity from the right

I see that when $t=t_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that since the ($x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)}, \dots, x_k^{(n)}$) and  $(\xi_n(t_1), \xi_n(t_2), \dots,\xi_n(t_k))$ as have the same finite dimensional distribution , convergence in probability of $\xi(t_{k_r})$ to $\xi(t)$ implies that $x_{k_r}^{(n)}$ converges in probablity to $x_k^{(n)}$

But how can i conclude for for all $t \in [t_0,T]$?